# SQL case return more than 1 row write a string

Tags: sql, group-by, subquery

I have a subquery in SELECT and sometimes it returns more than one row. I want to solve the problem like this:

- when more than 1 row write a string like 'multi'
- otherwise use the value description from comment table

Query:

```
select 
    s.id, 
    (select description from comment c where c.id = s.id) 
from student s;
```

thanks.

Comment: Have you tried count()?

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to have the multiple comments concatenated, instead of just the text 'multi'?

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: The problem is solved. My db was Oracle and I MUST have a string for multiple rows. Thank you guys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can join, aggregate, and use a conditional expression:

```
select 
    s.id,
    case when min(c.description) <> max(c.description) 
        then 'multi' 
        else min(c.description) 
    end description
from student s
left join comment c on c.id = s.id
group by s.id
```

You can also do this with a subquery, which avoids outer aggregation (it is handy if you need more columns from `students`):

```
select
    s.*,
    (
        select 
            case when min(c.description) <> max(c.description) 
                then 'multi' 
                else min(c.description) 
            end
        from comment c
        where c.id = s.id
    ) description
from student s
```

Comment: What happens when 0 row returns? Is it a null?

Comment: @Rezu: yes, in this case you get to the second branch of the `case` expression (`min(c.description)`), which yields `null`.